# WordPress: Echo an _e translation function

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, translation

I'm using WordPress' _e function to display both English and French text depending on which language version of my clients site they are on.

So this works:

```
<?php _e('[:en]<h3>Stack Overflow</h3>[:fr]<h3>Débordement de pile</h3>[:]'); ?>
```

But I have some functions that use the php echo statement to display HTML a href links and whatnot and it needs to work in there.

So I tried this:

```
echo _e('<p><a class="btn" href="https://yoursite.com/checkout">' . '[:en]Stack Overflow[:fr]Débordement de pile' . '</a></p></div>';
```

And it's throwing an error.

Any ideas of what the proper way to write this PHP code is?

Comment: _“And it's throwing an error.”_ - interesting; I’d have expected it to throw a baby or a vase … Kidding aside, saying there _is_ an error without saying _what_ that error is, is one of the un-cleverest things you can possibly do while describing a problem here.

Comment: I don’t know that `[:foo]` syntax, is that part of some specific translation/multi-language plugin or something? Anyway, it seems only logical that `[:]` is presumably the “end mark” for the parser to know where it has to _stop_ translating … where did that go in your second attempt?

Comment: 1) You're missing a parenthesis at the end.
2) I do not know the _e function from wordpress, but from your first example, it seems to print the text and not return it, so `echo _e('...');` would not be valid.
3) This won't work, you should do something like: `echo '<p>...'; _e('[:en]...'); echo '...</p>';`

Comment: First off, here's some info on what the _a function does: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/

Second, Naomi's suggestion worked great. A little bit of guesswork since the first attempt failed but the second try worked great,

Answer (score 0):

`_e()` is a function that automatically echos. For times when you need to return the translated string, use `__()` instead.

For example,

```
_e('[:en]<h3>Stack Overflow</h3>[:fr]<h3>Débordement de pile</h3>[:]');
echo __('[:en]<h3>Stack Overflow</h3>[:fr]<h3>Débordement de pile</h3>[:]');
```

do the same thing.